# Way to parse information from email to database

Tags: php, sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, vb.net

I have an email account that receives various requests to get free materials, for different items. These emails will usually contain name, item, quantity of item, address, state, zip. What makes it difficult is that all the emails are different, unstructured, and the data is usually buried in the emails, i.e. a forwarded email.

I want a way to get all the information and parse it into a ms sql database.

I know there are products that would work really well like http://www.email2db.com/, but at work we can't afford this.

I was thinking of creating a webservice that would input mail data posted from a third party site like cloudmail.com into a secondary website and then maybe creating a ruby script that would crawl the messages and extract addresses, etc. but this sounds pretty tedious.

Anyone know of a good, simple alternative, a custom script in ruby, php, vb.net or possibly an open source solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using a 3rd Party tool. I would use Microsoft Outlook VBA coding

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=52159

Comment: That will only solve the "receive the e-mail" part. Not the "read and interpret the e-mail" part, which OP is looking for. Besides, using Outlook **is** using a third-party tool.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think that magic words like 'webservice' and 'Ruby' will solve your problems?

If the mails you have to read are unstructured, you can't read them by code without investing a lot of time in writing that code. And still then you'll get messages you can't handle. This will be true for every programming language.

Why not create a simple web form where your users can enter that data, instead of manually typing an e-mail which in turn has to be interpreted?

Comment: I already have the form in vb, I am just trying to make the data entry more automated.

Comment: A form in Visual Basic is not a web form. I hope you understand my answer. You're trying to automatically read e-mails, which is hard since they aren't written in a certain format. So a better solution would be to let your clients enter a web form, instead of sending an e-mail.

Comment: I understand, but they do already have the capability of entering their info on a web form on our site. This solution is to be used internally, with the hope that our staff can from here on out, format received emails in a way to allow some script to pull all the basic info and send it to our db.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and was looking for something in PHP, so I looked for a parser first and then a DB Importer.

So I put them together and got this: https://github.com/escobar022/php-imap-ToDB

I found that the most important part was to know how an email breaks down(header,body,etc). So I found a parser class (https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap) that takes apart emails and retrieves the email in its essential parts and has the ability to download the items. I would recommend trying split up a complex email into parts and seeing what exactly is going on.

Once I understood this, I tried to send it using PHPmailer, and figured out how each part is needed to replicate the email. Once I figured this out, I stored these parts, breaking down the headers/body/attachments(relative paths) into the database.

Hope this helps!